# Javascript HTML DOM for dynamic element- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to change the background color of dynamic html elements, but the console shows 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined'.

Here's my full JS code:

```
 function showQuestion(){
    for(let i = 0; i < QuesPartA.length; i++){
      $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question">Number '+ parseInt(i+1) +'</div>');
      QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
          $(".questionBox").append('<span class="pilihan">'+option +' </span><br>');  
      });
     
  } 
  $(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>');
};

$(".questionBox").on("click", "span.pilihan", function() {
  const choice = document.getElementsByClassName(".pilihan")
  choice.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

I want to change the background color of `.pilihan` to be red when the user clicks, but such message appear on the console. Is this because the `.pilihan` is a dynamic element?

I appreciate every help.

Comment: const choice = document.getElementsByClassName("pilihan") don't use the dot here.

Comment: Side note: There's no point to `parseInt` in `parseInt(i+1)`, `i` is already a number. If there **were** a point (because it was a string), you'd want `parseInt(i, 10) + 1`, because otherwise you'd be *appending* the digit `1` and then parsing the result. (And you always want the second argument with `parseInt`.)

Comment: `choice` is a node list - it isn't a single element - even if there is only one element on the page with that class name

Comment: There are at least two issues above, called out by VPC and Randy: 1. `getElementsByClassName` accepts a **class name** (or names, separated with spaces), not a CSS selector, so you don't use the `.` (which is a CSS thign). 2. It returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element. If you want to do all of the elements, you'll need to loop over the collection. If you want only the first, you may want `document.querySelector(".pilihan").style.backgroundColor = "red";` (yes, with the `.`, because unlike `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelector` **does** accept a CSS selector).